# How does Disk Utility wipe the disk it's executing on?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, high-sierra, disk-format

Maybe I am misunderstanding the functionality as a whole but how does Disk Utility wipe the disk it's executing on? For example, if you were to erase yourself there would still be a hand left.

Comment: I don't think you can wipe your boot disk while booted on that disk.

Comment: If you want to wipe the boot disk with Disk Utility then you have to boot from another system (ie cd or usb etc) and run the Disk Utility from that system.

Comment: If you are referring to Recovery Mode, you are actually booting off of a different *partition.* Then when you erase the Mac HD you are erasing a *different* partition than the one the recovery Mode partition is on.

Comment: Theoretically it’s perfectly possible for disk utility to erase the partition “it’s on”. It just needs to load all its program contents into memory and can then operate from there without needing to read anything from disk. Once you close it, you’d obviously be stuck in no-mans land. The real issue lies more in how the running operating system hogs the file system and permissions surrounding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disk Utility` won't erase the partition from which your Mac boots.

Don't be confused by your ability to erase the boot "drive" while in Recovery mode. You are actually booting off a different partition on the same drive, one that is hidden, and this allows you to erase the boot partition.